# How to search document by oid in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I need get documents from db by oid, like:

```
Docs.objects(_id='4f4381f4e779897a2c000009')
```

But how to do it, if _id requires ObjectId object and even I try to set ObjectId from pymongo it doesn't work.

```
Docs.objects(_id=pymongo.objectid.ObjectId('4f4381f4e779897a2c000009'))
```

return empty list

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about just using the raw string:

```
Docs.objects.get(id='4f4381f4e779897a2c000009')
```

That is probably the easiest way ... right ?

Comment: Doesn't work for primary key though. Or am I the only one?

Answer (score 31):

This should work:

```
Docs.objects(pk='4f4381f4e779897a2c000009')
```

Comment: This one returns list. Not a single object.

Comment: @Raptor then use .first()

Answer (score 8):

Came to this question because I had a lot of trouble with this myself. It seems like PyMongo [changed this](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit/pull/88) and objectid is no longer inside pymongo and is now instead:

```
import bson
Doc.objects.get(id=bson.objectid.ObjectId('4f4381f4e779897a2c000009'))
```

Also, Mongoengine uses the name 'id' for the ObjectID field.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old, but in case someone looks at it around 2022:
This works fine with MongoDB Atlas + Mongoengine == 0.23.1

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
Doc.objects(_id=ObjectId("85a2c854002c893dd7756b5g"))
```