# flask-admin handle request the right way

Tags: flask, flask-admin

how can i handle the request from listview template. if i click the submit button in my custom_list.html the the variables were not output as string. what did i do wrong ?

[image]

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import flask_admin as admin
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_admin.contrib.mongoengine import ModelView
from flask_admin.actions import action

# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'DB': 'test_app'}

# Create models
db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)


class Website(db.Document):
    domain_name = db.StringField(max_length=200)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=160)
    meta_desc = db.StringField()


class WebsiteView(ModelView):

    list_template = 'custom_list.html'

    @action('create_meta', 'Create Meta', 'Are you sure you want to create meta data?')
    def action_createmeta(self, ids):

        print "this is my domain_name {} and this is my title {}".format(
            Website.domain_name, Website.title)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create admin
    admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example: MongoEngine')

    # Add views
    admin.add_view(WebsiteView(Website))

    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/custom_list.html

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %} 
{% block body %} 
    <h1>Custom List View</h1> 
    {{ super() }} 
{% endblock %}

{% block list_row_actions %} 
    {{ super() }} 

  <form class="icon" method="POST" action="/admin/website/action/">
    <input id="action" name="action" value="create_meta" type="hidden">
    <input name="rowid" value="{{ get_pk_value(row) }}" type="hidden">
    <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to create meta data?');" title="Create Meta">
      <span class="fa fa-ok icon-ok"></span>
    </button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the definitions of Website.domain_name not the values.

From the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#searching-our-posts-by-tag) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988352/how-to-search-document-by-oid-in-mongoengine) you need to do:

```
for id in ids:
    found_object = Website.objects.get(id=id)
    print "this is my domain_name {} and this is my title {}".format(
          found_object.domain_name, found_object.title)
```

EDIT: original post.

> Change the line
>
> ```
> print "this is my domain_name {} and this is my title {}".format(
>         Website.domain_name, Website.title)
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> print "this is my domain_name {} and this is my title {}".format(
>         Website.domain_name.data, Website.title.data)
> ```
>
> You are printing the objects not the posted data contained within them

Comment: when do so i get an error: AttributeError: 'StringField' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Try changing the `Website.domain_name` etc to `self.domain_name`. That way you are using the WebsiteView classes instantiated objects which inherit from Website. I do believe this is where your posted data is

Comment: have tried this before. get another error: AttributeError: 'WebsiteView' object has no attribute 'domain_name'. when i put .data behind i get the same error

Comment: What if you print `ids` I believe that will be the element you created, and you need to call a fetch from the database to get the elements to display

Comment: yes print ids puts out the ObjectID. can you tell me how can fetch data with ids attribute please.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#searching-our-posts-by-tag) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988352/how-to-search-document-by-oid-in-mongoengine) `Website.objects.get(id)`

Comment: this throws another error: nvalidQueryError: Not a query object: <built-in function id>. Did you intend to use key=value?

Comment: i also follow up the examples in your link. Website.objects.get(id=ids) throws this error: ValidationError: u"[u'56d4dd0067b3db65269d6d33']" is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string. Website.objects(pk=ids) throws the same error

Comment: IDs is a a list. You need to do a for loop to iterate over them

Comment: finally it works, thank you for your time and explantation. i was so confused about that. already read documentation and try a lot of combination but i cant get it to work. your answer is correct. thanks a lot for that